# How to skip or ignore programmatically a suite in CodeceptJS

Tags: javascript, testing, codeceptjs

As the test suite grows I need to be able to run something in BeforeSuite() which will connect to external suite and skip the suite if an external resource is unavailable.

```
Feature('External Server');

BeforeSuite((I) => {
  // Check if server is available and skip all scenarios if it is not
});

Scenario('Login to the server', (I) => {
  // Do not run this if the server is not available
})
```

I understand I could probably set a variable, but I think it would be nice if there was a way to tell the runner that a suite has been skipped.

The goal is to have a suite marked as skipped in the output eg:

```
Registration --
  ✓ Registration - pre-checks in 4479ms
  ✓ Registration - email validation in 15070ms
  ✓ Registration - password validation in 8194ms

External Server -- [SKIPPED]
  - Login to the server [SKIPPED]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe prepend `x` before every scenario in your feature? example `xScenario`. I don't think codecept supports something similar to `only` for features. it currently works with scenarios only as far as I know.

Comment: this is not "programmatically" as in depending on runtime conditions, but merely editing the source code of the tests, of course you could in a pipeline run some sed command to prepend the x before calling the tests run, but it's not the same

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
    Scenario.skip
```

in your step definition to skip a scenario.
Note: if any steps have been executed before skipping then it will still show it in the report

https://codecept.io/basics/#todo-test

Answer (score 0):

My answer is compiled from a number of comments on the CodeceptJS github and stackoverflow.  However, I can't recall the exact links or comments which helped me derive this solution, it's been at least a year, maybe two, since I started and have slowly modified this.

---

Edit: Found the github thread - https://github.com/codeceptjs/CodeceptJS/issues/661

Edit2: I wrote a post about "selective execution" (which avoids tagging unwanted tests with `skip` status) https://github.com/codeceptjs/CodeceptJS/issues/3544
I'll add a snippet at the bottom.

---

I'm on CodeceptJS 3.3.6

Define a hook file (eg: skip.js) and link it to your codeceptjs.conf.js file.

```js
exports.config = { 
...
  plugins: {
    skipHook: {
      require: "../path/to/skip.js",
      enabled: true,
    }
  }
...
}
```

The basic code in skip.js is

```js
module.exports = function () {
  event.dispatcher.on(event.test.before, function (test) {
    const skipThisTest = decideSkip(test.tags);
    if (skipThisTest) {
      test.run = function skip() {
        this.skip();
      };
      return;
    }
  });
};
```

I've defined a decision function `decideSkip` like so:

```js
function decideSkip(testTags) {
  if (!Array.isArray(testTags)) {
    output.log(`Tags not an array, don't skip.`);
    return false;
  }

  if (testTags.includes("@skip")) {
    output.log(`Tags contain [@skip], should skip.`);
    return true;
  }

  if (
    process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT !== "development" &&
    testTags.includes("@stageSkip")
  ) {
    output.log(`Tags contain [@stageSkip], should skip on staging.`);
    return true;
  }
}
```

(Mine is a bit more complicated, including evaluating whether a series of test case ids are in a provided list but this shows the essence.  Obviously feel free to tweak as desired, the point is a boolean value returned to the defined event listener for `event.test.before`.)

Then, using BDD:

```
@skip @otherTags
Scenario: Some scenario
  Given I do something first
  When I do another thing
  Then I see a result
```

Or standard test code:

```js
const { I } = inject();
Feature("Some Feature");

Scenario("A scenario description @tag1 @skip @tag2", async () => {
  console.log("Execute some code here");
});
```

I don't know if that will necessarily give you the exact terminal output you want `External Server -- [SKIPPED]`; however, it does notate the test as skipped in the terminal and report it accordingly in allure or xunit results; at least insofar as CodeceptJS `skip()` reports it.

---

For "selective execution" (which is related but not the same as "skip"), I've implemented a custom `mocha.grep()` utilization in my bootstrap.  A key snippet is as follows.  To be added either to a bootstrap anonymous function on codecept.conf.js or some similar related location.

```js
  
  const selective = ["tag1", "tag2"];
  const re = selective.join("|");
  const regex = new RegExp(re);
  mocha.grep(regex);
```